# Creating remote repository for practice on my machine

Tags: git, git-bash

Hello fellow developers.

My manager wants me to learn git, and I'm understanding the concept, but its not really working for me. I'm trying to add a remote repository that I created (as he suggested). Since git documentation says you can add remote repository with

```
git remote add origin <url>
```

so my junior developer idea was to just create a repository in a different windows folder - c:/Remote/.git, and punch that in as my url.

```
git remote add origin c:/Remote/.git
```

of course it didn't work when I tried to push onto it. Also, I'm not getting how branching works, I've created several different branches, but it seems like they all share the same stages/commits. What's the point then, I thought the whole idea is that these branches would have different versions of the code, but any change I make just seems to affect all of them.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: I believe you should invest on read some pages from: http://git-scm.com/doc - truly study those. Perhaps you will not need hooks our a complex branch's setups, so, grab the first chapters and go from there. This was how I started.

Answer (score 0):

Git's built on the unix toolkit so it uses unix-style pathnames.

Try `/c/Remote` if it's not bare; specifying the  `.git` subdirectory explicitly in the remote path works but it's not usual and not necessary to do that for working repos.

Having the repository directory separate like that works with bare repos, but since there's no worktree the extra layer is useless, unaesthetic, and the convention is to just suffix the name so its pathname should be`/c/Remote.git` if bare.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot. I had to use /c/Remote/.git though.

Comment: Hunh. I did try it on my msysgit install, don't know what to tell you there